# Wordpress wp_set_object_terms does not assign product to custom taxonomy

Tags: php, plugin-development

I have create a custom taxonomy called `regions` with acf. and have create also a select option on dokan multivendor dashboard where they can create new product

```
<?php
$regions = get_terms([
    'hierarchical' => 1,
    'show_option_none' => '',
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    'taxonomy' => 'region'
]);
?>
    <label for="regions"><?php esc_html_e('Region', 'your-text-domain'); ?></label><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="region_id" id="region_id" value="">
    <select name="regions" class="dokan-form-control">
        <option value=""><?php esc_html_e('Select Region', 'your-text-domain'); ?></option>
        <?php foreach ($regions as $region) {
        $parent_categories = get_terms([
            'taxonomy' => 'region',
            'hide_empty' => false,
            'parent' => $region->term_id
        ]);
        if (!empty($parent_categories)) { // check if there are any child categories
            ?>
            <?php foreach ($parent_categories as $parent_category) {
                $child_categories = get_terms([
                'taxonomy' => 'region',
                'hide_empty' => false,
                'parent' => $parent_category->term_id
                ]);
                if (!empty($child_categories)) { // check if there are any child categories
                ?>
                <optgroup label="<?php echo $parent_category->name; ?>">
                    <?php foreach ($child_categories as $child_category) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $child_category->term_taxonomy_id; ?>" id="in-region-<?php echo $child_category->term_taxonomy_id; ?>"> <?php echo $child_category->name; ?> </option>
                    <?php } ?>
                </optgroup>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

and now i try to assign this post id when its created to regions like this

```
//path: dokan-lit/includes/Dashboard/Templates/Products.php

public function handle_product_add() {
    if ( isset( $postdata['add_product'] ) ) {
            $post_title     = sanitize_text_field( $postdata['post_title'] );
            $post_content   = wp_kses_post( $postdata['post_content'] );
            $post_excerpt   = wp_kses_post( $postdata['post_excerpt'] );
            $featured_image = absint( sanitize_text_field( $postdata['feat_image_id'] ) );
            <!-- i have added this line here to get regions id  -->
            $regionId       = sanitize_text_field($postdata['regions']);
            
            $product_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );

                
                if ( $product_id ) {
                    
                    // and trying to assign this product id to region id like this.
                    wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $regionId, 'region');

}
```

But i see this is not working. Any idea how to fix this problem?

Comment: have you confirmed that `wp_set_object_terms` is running and if so how? Can you confirm that `wp_insert_post` worked and that the `$product_id` variable is not empty/null/false? Where does `$postdata` come from? It seems to pop out of thing air, my initial expectation is that `if ( isset( $postdata['add_product'] ) ) {` will never be true because `$postdata` doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks for replying. `$postdata = wp_unslash( $_POST );` this row is above my code. I am not posting all code couse is a long function.  But also i cant confirm if `wp_insert_post` or `$product_id` couse i am just editing this plugin but wihle trying to understand code, i thinks is okay couse inside `if ($product_id)` have also another functions who use ` wp_set_object_terms( $product_id, $cat_ids, 'product_cat' );`

Comment: if there are missing parts from `handle_product_add` can you ensure that enough of it is present that we don't have mystery variables, and that there are comments stating that code is missing? a `....` on its own line is usually enough to indicate parts are missing, and in this case it's important to know, especially since people can and do ask questions like this were `$postdata` is undefined

Answer (score 0):

I can see few potential issues here:

1. wp_insert_post returns post_id or 0 or WP_Error, if you will have WP_Error it will still pass the `if ( $porduct_id )`. So here you have one potential issue.
2. In description you wrote, that you create fields called "regions", and in code you have `wp_set_object_terms($product_id, $regionId, 'region');` so here we have "region" no "regions". Not sure if you misspelled in the code or in the description.
3. Last thing is here: `<option value="<?php echo $child_category->term_taxonomy_id; ?>"` probably it should be `$child_category->term_id`

Hope any of this will point you to the issue.

Comment: Thanks for replying. i just changed the`$child_category->term_id` but no difference. Also i try both  names `region` and `regions` but still no difference

Comment: `wp_insert_post returns post_id or 0 or WP_Error, if you will have WP_Error it will still pass the if ( $porduct_id ). So here you have one potential issue.` i does not understand very good what this mean. I also am beginer on wp development

Comment: `WP_Error` is an error object with an error message inside, if there is a problem then the `$product_id` variable will not contain the product ID, it will contain an error object, which you do not check for. Since `if ( $product_id )` is checking " is this a thing or is it false/null?" `WP_Error` objects are a thing so it succeeds when it should not. You should look up `WP_Error` and how to handle it, how to grab the message inside it, etc